# How to fetch one to many relation data using single query in postgre sql

Tags: postgresql, relationship, one-to-many

I have two tables category and sub_category

category

| category_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | category1 |
| 2 | category2 |

sub_category

| sub_category_id | name | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | subcategory1 | 1 |
| 2 | subcategory2 | 1 |

i want to get data in the following format:

```
{

  category:{
         category_id:1,
         name:category1
         }
  subCategories:[
               {
                subCategory_id:1
                name:subcategory1
               },
               {
                subCategory_id:2
                name:subcategory2
                },
             ]
}
```

currently i am getting data using left join and then manually iterating the list to create the above format .It will be helpful if i can the data from database directly  in the above format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [`json_build_object`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) to return `JSON` and the aggregate function [`json_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html) to create *subCategories* `JSON` array :

```
select
  c.category_id,
  json_build_object(
     'category', json_build_object(
                            'category_id', c.category_id,
                            'name', c.name
                    ),
     'subCategories',  json_agg(
                             json_build_object(
                                  'subCategory_id', sc.sub_category_id,
                                   'name', sc.name
                             ))
                        
  ) as json_
from category c
inner join sub_category sc on sc.category_id = c.category_id
group by c.category_id, c.name
```

Result :

```
category_id json_
1          {
           "category":{
              "category_id":1,
              "name":"category1"
           },
           "subCategories":[
              {
                 "subCategory_id":2,
                 "name":"subcategory2"
              },
              {
                 "subCategory_id":1,
                 "name":"subcategory1"
              }
           ]
        }
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/51xWnDly)

Comment: Thanks , I haven't tried using json .This just opened new perspective for me.